# How to get multiple Spinner value?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a Fragment with 12 Spinners and I don't need to perform any action until the user click on a button.

All my Spinners looks like this.(Showing only 2)

```
 <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinnerP1Type"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    style="@style/spinner_style"
    android:entries="@array/powerTypes"
    android:gravity="top"
    />
 <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinnerP2Type"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    style="@style/spinner_style"
    android:entries="@array/powerTypes"
    android:gravity="top"
    />
```

All of them have pretty similar name, and there's no other spinners.
Is possible to process them in a loop instead of creating one new object by each one?

```
Spinner SpinP1 = getView().findViewById(R.id.spinnerP1Type);
Spinner SpinP2 = getView().findViewById(R.id.spinnerP2Type);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to create an array of ids to loop over:

```
int[] spinnerIds = new int[] {R.id.spinnerP2Type, R.id.spinnerP1Type);

for (int spinnerId : spinnerIds) {
    Spinner spinner = getView().findViewById(spinnerId);
    // etc.
}
```

Comment: The second item in your array should be P2?

Comment: @E_Blue Yes, that was a copy/paste error. It is fixed now.

Comment: This is more of my style. I'd create an array for the `Spinner`s too.

Comment: @Darkman but then if you add another spinner, you still have to add its id to the Spinner id-array, which is much more error-prone as you might forget to do that. And it requires more code. But it's still another way to do it.

Comment: @Noah I agree your solution is much more flexible. It needs a little more work if there are other views in the same LinearLayout mixed with the Spinners.

Comment: That is why `if (child instanceof Spinner)` is there :)

Comment: Is possible to do the same with Spinners from another Fragment? Both fragments are visible but I'm getting null from getview(); probably because is in another Fragment.

Comment: @E_Blue Fragments should be self-contained. One fragment shouldn't try to interact directly with views in another fragment.

Comment: So I should use the classic method of change an static variables and read it after? I must place them in the main activity Right? Or maybe I can call a function that returns the string that I need from the second fragment.

Comment: @E_Blue Static variables are intended for storing values that are associated with the class not any specific instance. They are often abused for other purposes that don't meet this criteria. Ask yourself: if I have multiple instances of this fragment in the same activity, should they all share the same value for this variable? If the answer is no, then a static variable is the wrong solution. Instead, use method calls to communicate between fragments.

Comment: @E_Blue https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate describes the suggested pattern to communicate between two fragments. I found this by googling "communicate between two fragments".

Answer (score 2):

Wrap all the spinners in a ViewGroup (use either LinearLayout or ConstraintLayout) and then when the button is clicked, run a for loop and call `getChildAt(loopIndex)` on that ViewGroup. The ViewGroup should already have been instantiated with `findViewById(R.id.the_container_name)`

The code below

```
<LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/spinner_container"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     `...` >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerP1Type"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        style="@style/spinner_style"
        android:entries="@array/powerTypes"
        android:gravity="top"
        />
     <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerP2Type"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        style="@style/spinner_style"
        android:entries="@array/powerTypes"
        android:gravity="top"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then call:

```
            Linearlayout container = getView().findViewById(R.id.spinner_container);
            
            for (int i = 0; i < container.getChildCount(); i++) {
              View child = container.getChildAt(i);
              if (child instanceof Spinner) {
              Spinner spinner = (Spinner) child;
              spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new SimpleOnItemSelectedListener());

               }
         }
        
        
    /**
     * Listener
     */
    public class SimpleOnItemSelectedListener implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    
       @Override
       public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    
       }
    
       @Override
       public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
    
       }
    }
```

Note: `SimpleOnItemSelectedListener` implements `AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener`

Comment: The spinner currently are inside a LinearLayout. I want to process them after because I need to create a string using all of them when the user click on the button. In languages like VB.NET you can create a string and search that object by its name using a string, not and integer like in java. So when the for loop is running you create strings like Sp1, next Sp2, next Sp3 and uses that string to search the object. That's not possible here?

Comment: I updated my answer

Comment: Thanks. The line inside the for loop now is in red; Android Studio says that I must to cast the View to a Spinner. Also I forgot that for every Spinner there's a TextView with the description of what the Spinner under does.

Comment: Done. Check if it work now

Comment: Put the complete code !!

Comment: @E_Blue You might want to consider creating a custom View subclass which encapsulates the `TextView` and `Spinner` into a single view. This can make it easier to works with them together.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice that means my code would break because `getChildAt()` would retrieve the custom view and to solve this, you would need to call `getChildAt()` on the custom view to retrieve that Spinner

Comment: @Noah Yes, this suggestion would take some additional work. What I have in mind is encapsulating manipulation of the Spinner in the custom view class.